# using facebook graph with express

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express

I'm looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5574902/1893672) and I don't know how to use it with express. lets say at route `/fbtest` I want to show info on a fb user. the answer suggest that i make a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_NAME_OR_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` and I would get the information on the user. I have a client ID and a client secret how do I get the access token?

```
app.get("/fbtest", function(req, res){
    make request to fb 
    set var to the returned data
    res.end(the var)
})
```

through out the fb documentation I see something like `GET /me/{namespace}:{action-type}/{object-type}` I really want to use something like that for something I need. should I really type in the letters "me" or the username?

I was googling and I see [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) that my help but I don't understand the examples like `FB.api('4', function (res) {` what is `4`?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the access token, you need to follow oAuth. You need to send the user to Facebook and ask for permission. If the user permits those actions, s/he will be redirected back to your web site with access token.
2. `/me/` would work for the logged in user. It's equivalent to the username or user ID for the logged in user.

Comment: I understand that but I dont know how to send the request . I'm used to sending get requests in app.get and now I have to send a get request in an app.get() (is that how to do it) I think to get the info from FB to the  `/fbtest`